aws dedicated host: fully dedicated vs sharing?
Going through AWS documentation, it has following to say on dedicated host:

Are not these 2 points conflicting? If server capacity can be shared  wit other accounts, then how can it be a fully dedicated server?

From Work with shared Dedicated Hosts - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud:

Dedicated Host sharing enables Dedicated Host owners to share their Dedicated Hosts with other AWS accounts or within an AWS organization. This enables you to create and manage Dedicated Hosts centrally, and share the Dedicated Host across multiple AWS accounts or within your AWS organization.

Let's say you are a company with 10 AWS Accounts (it is quite common for a company to even have hundreds of AWS Accounts, since they offer segregation for billing and security purposes). If you create a Dedicated Host, you can 'share' that host with other AWS Accounts within your own company. This is more economical than having to use the Dedicated Host within a single AWS Account.
When using a Dedicated Host, the AWS Account that creates the Dedicated Host is charged for the whole host. When instances are launched on the Dedicated Host, there is no charge (because the whole host computer is already being payed for).
Summary: The host is dedicated to you. But you can choose how it can be uesd.

Got it. Basically it means host is for my org only, and won't be shared with any other org.
